# Uncertainty principle and entanglement state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am about the following wikipedia article: [EPR paradox. Mathematical formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox#Mathematical_formulation).

Operators corresponding to spin along $x, y$ and $z$ axes are $S_x, S_y, S_z$. Eigenstates of $S_z$ are $\left|+z\right>$ and $\left|-z\right>$. Eigenstates  of $S_x$ are $\left|+x\right>$ and $\left|-x\right>$. We consider 2 particles with the following wave function

$$\left|\psi\right> = \frac{\left|+z\right>_1\left|-z\right>_2 - \left|-z\right>_1\left|+z\right>_2}{\sqrt{2}} = - \frac{\left|+x\right>_1\left|-x\right>_2 - \left|-x\right>_1\left|+x\right>_2}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I.e. if we measure the spin of the first particle along $z$ and got $s_z = -z$ then the second particle will have the spin $s_z = +z$. The same result for $x$ axe: if we got for the first particle $s_x = +x$ spin then the second one will have $s_x = -x$ spin.

The article says that

> It remains only to show that $S_x$ and $S_z$ cannot simultaneously possess definite values in quantum mechanics. One may show in a straightforward manner that no possible vector can be an eigenvector of both matrices. More generally, one may use the fact that the operators do not commute.

The operators $S_x$ and $S_z$ really don't commute:
$$\left[S_x,S_z\right] = -i \hbar S_y $$

Uncertainty principle says that 
$$\Delta s_x \Delta s_z \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}\left| \left<S_y\right>\right|$$

I assume that  $\left<S_y\right> = \left<\psi\right|S_y\left|\psi\right>$, but the problem is that $\left<\psi\right|S_y\left|\psi\right> = 0$ and as result
$$\Delta s_x \Delta s_z \ge 0.$$ Thus potentially no problem to measure spin along $x$ and $z$ axes in the same time i. e. uncertainty principle does not apply any limitation on this.

Could anybody point me what's wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are correct that two operators not commuting does *not* show that they have no simultaneous eigenvectors. In fact, all it shows is that there is no *basis* of simultaneous eigenvectors, but in general, the existence of a single or a few such vectors is not forbidden.
2. It is nevertheless true that there are no simultaneous eigenstates of the angular momentum operators $S_x$ and $S_z$. Here's why:

   Without loss of generality we assume that we are in an irreducible representation of the rotation group with spin $s$, so it has dimension $2s+1$ and is spanned by eigenvectors $\lvert -s\rangle,\dots,\lvert s\rangle$ of $S_z$ with eigenvalues from $-s$ to $s$ in integer increments. Since all their eigenvalues are different, these are the only eigenvectors of $S_z$ on this space, so any simultaneous eigenvector of $S_x$ and $S_z$ must be one of these. Now we recall that the combinations $S_\pm = S_x \pm \mathrm{i} S_y$ are raising and lowering operators for the $S_z$-eigenstates, i.e.
   $$ S_+\lvert j\rangle = \lvert j + 1 \rangle \quad \land \quad S_-\lvert j\rangle = \lvert j - 1 \rangle,$$
   where the states on the r.h.s. is zero in case $j+1 > s$ or $j-1 < -s$. We have that $S_x = \frac{1}{2}(S_+ + S_-)$ and therefore
   $$ S_x \lvert j\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(S_+\lvert j\rangle + S_-\lvert j\rangle)  =\frac{1}{2}(\lvert j+ 1\rangle + \lvert j-1\rangle)\neq \lvert j\rangle,$$
   so none of the $S_z$ eigenstates is an $S_x$ eigenstate.